# Rails: Image problem with subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hey all,
I created a page with some images located at public/other_images
So in my image tag i point to '/../other_images/filename.jpg' and this works.
But when I put it online, I've put it at mydomain.com/sub and now the image in my source points to sub/../other_images/filename.jpg and ofcourse it can't be found.
Is there any way to tell rails it does'nt have to take that subdomain in his path?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you specify path only "/other_images/filename.jpg", it will work properly. See more documentation on [image_path](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_path)

> But when I put it online, I've put it at mydomain.com/sub and now the image in my source points to sub/../other_images/filename.jpg and ofcourse it can't be found.

I am not sure about why it's happening but generally it should access file by "mydomain.com/other_images/filename.jpg"... **sub** should not come into the picture during generating image path